# Insert Table of Contents in chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc, etoc

Any idea of how to create a mini table of contents (TOC) in the beginning of a chapter? Not the ordinary TOC in the beginning of the report, but a mini TOC in the beginning of a chapter (like, containing the specific chapter).

Comment: Aloha to a new TeX.SX user! You want to have a look on `etoc` perhaps. `minitoc` is unmaintained for years now, although it's a quite a nice package. Please provide some minimal document to work with too

Comment: Tthe `minitoc` package, and the `titletoc` (part of `titlesec`) packages are designed for such things.

Comment: This question is duplicate?

Comment: Thank you very much. The etoc was exactly was i was looking for.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer any idea if the etoc is not working with memoir or any other packages?

Comment: @Anders: `etoc` with `memoir` needs some more setup, unfortunately. I'll try to figure out

Comment: @Anders: See the change at the end of my answer. Is this what you mean? I can't say much on side effects with other packages, however

Answer (score 14):

Here is a quick (stock) answer for this:

The easiest way is to use `etoc` package and its `\localtableofcontents` macro, at the appropriate place.
The manual is at https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % Global toc
\chapter{First}
\localtableofcontents % local toc
\section{First section}

\chapter{Second}
\localtableofcontents

\section{First section of 2nd chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Here is the `memoir` version.

For some reasons I can't figure out (the manual of `etoc` is not really clear in this case) it's necessary to use `\localtableofcontents*`.
The individual `tocdepth` can be controlled with the `\etocsettocdepth.toc{sectionlevel}` command (note the `.toc` in the macro name`)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoc}


\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\etocsettocdepth{subsection}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Global toc
\chapter{First}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{section}

\localtableofcontents*
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection -- not in the local toc}

\blindtext

\chapter{Second}
\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsection}
\localtableofcontents*

\section{First section of 2nd chapter}
\subsection{First subsection of first section of 2nd chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot shows the local toc for the 2nd chapter

Comment: The non-starred `\localtableofcontents` obey `memoir`'s convention to create (by default) for each TOC a chapter like entry in the `.toc` file. This creates a bit of havoc, which can be circumvented via issuing (after the global TOC): `\etocmemoirtoctotocfmt {section}{\contentsname}` to have the `.toc` file contain a section, not a chapter entry. The starred variants obey again `memoir`'s convention to **not** create a `.toc` entry. In both cases issuing  `\etocarticlestyle` after the main toc is recommended in order to use section headings and not chapter headings as per memoir default.